# Верстка таблицы с отсутствующими ячейками

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется таблицеподобная структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая ячейка представляет собой карточку с текстовой информацией. Цифрами обозначил порядок заполнения ячеек из БД. Общая ширина и высота таблицы постоянна, размер ячеек тоже. Тощина границ одинакова. Изменяется только количество ячеек в столбце. Ячеек порядка полутора сотен.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верстать подобную структуру? 
У меня есть две идеи:

1. Верстка собственно таблицей, в которой к необходимым ячейками добавлять модификатор (empty-cells: hide), так мы сможем быстро создать таблицу и изменить ее внешний вид, толщина границ будет везде одинакова. Проблему вижу только в заполнении ее данными. Как задать последовательность заполнения таблицы и игнорировать пустые ячейки? Еще таблица, на сколько я знаю, будет дольше рендериться, чем блоки.
2. Верстка блоками. Здесь нет особого понимания. Тут вижу одни проблемы с позиционированием блока, выравниванием толщины границ. Возможно, будет проще заполнение контентом за счет обхода блоков в цикле и быстрее завершаться рендер за счет блоков.

Направьте, пожалуйста, в нужное русло и укажите недостатки подходов

Comment: А чем определяется структура таблицы?

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko Ничем, виде заранее задан. В эскизе я вольно изобразил, чтобы показать, что столбцы в таблице могут содержаться столбы разной высоты. В действительности таблица больше, и начинается с высоты 10, потом 8, затем несколько стобцов по 6  т.д.

Comment: Тогда лучше использовать первый способ. Таблицы для таблиц. Просто задайте ячейкам, которые планируете заполнять какой нибудь класс и по нему определяйте, что заполнять, а что нет

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko Да, добавлять модификатор это здравая мысль. Но как мне обходить все ячейки для заполнения контентом и игнорировать невидимые?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вашей задачи лучше подойдет таблица, так как из блоков вам так или иначе придется строить таблицу. 
Что бы заполнять только нужные ячейки, можете добавить к ячейкам которые планируете заполнять, какой нибудь класс.

Например так:

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('used')
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
cells[i].textContent = i;   
}
```

```css
td {
  empty-cells: hide
}
```

```html
<table border=1 boredercolor=black>
  <tr>
    <td class="used"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="used"></td>
    <td class="used"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="used"></td>
    <td class="used"></td>
    <td class="used"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду совершествовать этот вариант